# The ambiguity of: "resent your message"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, irregular-verbs

I am not a native English speaker. Thus I am not sure about the meaning of an email I received. Since the writer is important to me and I depend on his good will, I am afraid to ask him what he wanted to say.

I had sent a normal email asking about the progress a third person made since there was some delay. The reply was

> "I have resent your message, I already spoke to him last week".

I first thought, OK, he has forwarded the mail. But now I have seen that a more formal translation would be "I am angry about your (in some sense annoying) message". Unfortunately, the writer was also not a native English speaker.

Now I am wondering how "resent" is typically or most commonly used.

Comment: If it was the regular verb "resent" then it would have been used in the past tense  "**I have resented...**" instead, the past participle of the irregular verb "(re)send" is *(re)sent*, so it was used correctly in the message you received

Comment: Thanks, however, the writer was also not a native English speaker. This makes it plausible that he was not aware of the correct grammar.  My dictionaries (and the Linguee-website) suggested the meaning "being angry". Is this really the common meaning ?

Comment: The usual recommendation is to add a hyphen to disambiguate (eg re-sign from resign) where necessary. Though this rule of thumb is not universally obeyed, even among native speakers. In fact, ODO uses resign where AHD, Collins and RHK Webster's insist on re-sign, and I think all list resend.  The omission of the hyphen rather than the mangled grammar is far more likely.

Comment: Yes, to "resent someone" or "something" means to take offense. In the case of the non-native speaker then you really need to communicate with that person and clear up any misunderstanding there may have been. Just write, or phone, and thank them for passing on your message (forwarding the email?) ask if everything is OK and/or how you might be able to help more.

Comment: Literally ["S/Z"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/Z),  by Roland Barthes

Comment: Not answering the question (there are good answers already), but you should ask yourself if there was anything in your message that might cause resentment. The ambiguity only really exists if there was, because why would he get angry about it if there was nothing in it to offend? If there was something in your message that could potentially upset him, then perhaps you should consider discussing it with them anyway regardless of whether they were actually offended.

Comment: Since neither of you is a native speaker, it is not possible for the "rules" of English to determine for sure what was intended.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth your comment is worth at least as much as any current answer -- consider posting a discussion of hyphen use as an answer

Comment: @Carl Witthoft It's been covered here before. I leave you to do the in-house search.

Comment: "have resent" _avoids_ the ambiguity.

Comment: I get the feeling that you want people to say which interpretation they think is correct.  Since I keep getting attacked by the site police for trying to give real-world answers… perhaps you might like to actually ask the above?  (The obvious useless correct answer is that “resend” is not typically used to mean “forward”.)

Answer (score 29):

> "I have resent your message, I already spoke to him last week". I first thought, OK, he has forwarded the mail.

That is indeed what he meant. This is based on the verb "to resend" ([ODO link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resend)).

His usage of "to resend" a bit off. It implies that he has sent the message a *second* time, which is not the case here (the first time, **you** were the one who sent the message, not him).

A more correct usage would be:

> I sent the message. Then I noticed that I sent it without the needed attachment, so I resent the message with the attachment.

*I* sent it the first time, and then *I* resent it. It was the same sender both times (me).

Regardless of correctness, what the person who wrote to you meant to say is that he forwarded the message.

---

> But now I have seen that a more formal translation would be "I am angry about your (in some sense annoying) message".

You're thinking of the verb "to resent", which does mean feeling bitter or indignated ([ODO link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resent)). But this doesn't actually fit in the current sentence:

> I have resent your message

Grammatically, this can only be the present perfect tense of "to resend".

There is no grammatically correct interpretation that allows for "to resent" to be used here.

---

Compare this to other cases in which "to resent" could be grammatically correct:

> I **resent** your message.

This is ambiguous between the two options:

- The present tense of "to resent" => "Today, I am offended by your message"
- The past tense of "to resend" => "Yesterday, I sent your message again"

> I **have resented** your message.

This can only be the present perfect tense of "to resent". But it sounds a bit forced.

> I **have resentment for** your message.

"resentment" is the noun form of "to resent". But it sounds a bit forced, it would be more idiomatic to say that you *carry* resentment for something.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed account, I did not expect this deepness.

Comment: People often use the word "resend" to refer to forwarding. The message was sent the first time to them, and the second time from them. While it's not the same person doing the sending, it's the same message.

Comment: "I have resented your message."  would sound less forced with a time frame.  "I have resented your message since you sent it three weeks ago."

Comment: “It implies that he has sent the message a second time” To me, it implies *somebody* already sent the message so I wouldn't find it “a bit off”. But granted, I am not a native speaker either.

Comment: From the context, I don't think that the usage of "resend" is really that wrong (your first section).

Comment: @Kevin "resented" is totally ungrammatical English.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: No, it's not. "I have resented his presence since he arrived" is totally grammatical.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai resented as in the past tense of resent, not a screwed up past tense of resend

Comment: @Kevin oh, lol.

Comment: For what it's worth, as a native English speaker, I have heard people refer to "resend" to simply mean forward or relay. Though it probably is not technically correct, it's not particularly uncommon.

Comment: As a native speaker, I disagree with the claim that I can't "resend" a message if you were the person who originally sent it. It has been sent twice, so the second sending was a resending. It doesn't matter who sent it on each occasion. For a direct comparison, the Forth Bridge [famously needed continual applications of paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_Bridge#Maintenance). This is referred to as "repainting", even though the bridge was built in the 1880s so anybody painting it today definitely didn't apply the original paint.

Comment: Ironically, your "more correct" version includes "so I resent the message", which _is_ ambiguous, though it's obvious that the intended meaning is "sent again" rather than "am bitter about".

Answer (score 9):

“Resent” is one of those words in English whose meaning depends on the pronunciation more than the spelling. *In this case*, the pronunciation is (approximately) /riˈsɛnt/, is often written “re-sent”, and means “sent again”. What you found in the dictionary would be pronounced /rɪˈzɛnt/, and carries the anger-related meaning you are asking about.

Pronunciation information: https://tophonetics.com/
Definitions: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/resent

Answer (score 3):

If he has said "I have resent.." rather than "I resent.." it is more likely to (s)he intended the meaning to be re-sent rather than making the grammatical mistake of using have where it does not belong.

Best to chat in person if unsure and have a laugh about misunderstandings.

Comment: Thanks, to give it another twist, the writer was also not a native English speaker. Do you think the meaning "being angry" is common at all ? I know I should try a chat, but the situation is a bit complicated.

Comment: The anger-related meaning is quite common, but usually discernable from context in writing. The context here makes it pretty clear that the intended meaning is "re-sent", "sent again" (see my answer to this question).

Comment: As Jeff pointed out there are some words that are written the same but have different intonation. English is a stress-timed language (albeit weakly so). Resent (anger) is stressed on the 2nd syllable; resent (re-sent) is on the 1st or both. Similar to offer (verb) and offer (noun)

Comment: It does sound a complicated situation when  queryin a perceived recent resentment over resentment may cause resentment to be resent.

Comment: @PaulChilds - I don't pronounce/stress offer(n) and offer(v) differently.

Comment: You should. The stress is subtle but there.

Comment: @PaulChilds OED has  Brit. /ˈɒfə/,  U.S. /ˈɔfər/, /ˈɑfər/ for both noun and verb, fwiw. How do you say them?

Comment: @SandyR In the context of email, it's overwhelmingly likely that "resent" means "sent again" rather than "was angry about". Almost every time somebody talks about email, they're talking about sending or receiving it. "Send" is definitely the verb you expect to see when email is being discussed.

Comment: This is why AP style and careful editors call for words like "re-sent" to be spelled one way and "resent" to be spelled another way. Same with "re-create" and "recreate."